# 401 unauthorized response calling REST api after enabling Kerberos in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, kerberos

I have Sharepoint 2013 on-prem Farm installed in a developer 2008 server.

The database, the app and the frontend are all installed in the same server.

Everything works fine until I decide to enable Kerberos.

I follow guidelines in this link to proceed :

https://blog.blksthl.com/2012/09/26/the-first-kerberos-guide-for-sharepoint-2013-technicians/

Note that My DNS name is registered with an A record and not a CNAME.

Also, I register two SPN (Service Principal Names) with the following format :

- HTTP/DNS HOST name
- HTTP/DNS FQDN

Now that Kerberos is installed, I get 401 unauthorized response when making a call to REST api.

I try with _api and also with listdata.svc.

For example, a request like this :

http://my_web_app/my_site_collection/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('name of my list')/items

returns something like that :

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
```

I find it strange to see NTLM. I thought it would be rather Kerberos in the WWW-Authenticate.

Any idea ?